# не подключается pgadmin4 к psql14 на macOS

Tags: postgresql, macos, pgadmin4

при попытке подключиться к psql14 с macOS через pgAdmin4 пишет: 
`connection failed: :1), port 5433 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`, что делать?

Comment: Проверить, что у пользователя postgres вообще задан пароль. Проверить правильность пользователя и пароля, в котором желательно не иметь особых символов. Удостоверится, что в pg_hba.conf разрешен вход по паролю. Подключиться можно и по psql утилите. Более подробно по примерным действиям можно подсмотреть в ответах на EnSO тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695962/password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres